# How to add custom header when composing an email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

For example, I would like to add the [`In-Reply-To`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4) field myself, because I want to [respond to an archived message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/reply-to-mailman-archived-message). I’m on macOS, but I don’t think this is platform dependent, so I did’t add the platform tag.

Comment: "`I don’t think this is platform `" - I think that it is mail client dependent.

Comment: @Mawg Yes, the mail client is Microsoft Outlook, as shown from the tag. My specific version is [tag:microsoft-outlook-2016], but I also tagged the general [tag:microsoft-outlook] since I think it applies to all the versions.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. My apologies (+1)

Comment: Maybe you can do something with VBA. See http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=5&messageid=27515

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that in Microsoft Office Outlook for Windows with [VBA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty). Outlook for macOS (Android, iOS) doesn't support VBA, sorry.

Comment: Although this isn’t cross-platform solution, I still upvoted and hope it helps someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest versions of Outlook - at least with an Office 365 account (not sure otherwise) - you can now script Outlook using JavaScript rather than VBA and that should be cross-platform.

Have a look at the "Get Add-ins" button and check out Microsoft's Script Lab for Outlook addin.

[image]